# Cloudformation parameter for list of AMIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-auto-scaling, aws-ssm

I'm creating a cloudformation for ecs cluster over an auto scaling group. In the launch configurations for the auto scaling group, i want to have a choice in specifying the ECS optimized AMI Id. Right now I have the following parameter:

```
"AutoScalingGroupImageId": {
   "Default" : "/aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2016-English-Full-SQL_2017_Standard",
   "Description" : "The AMI Id to be specified for the ASG",
   "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>"            
}
```

It needs to be something like `List<AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>>` from which i could choose the AMI Id for the required windows server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct such as `List<AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>>` is officially **not supported**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html):

> AWS CloudFormation **doesn't support** the following SSM parameter type:  **Lists of SSM parameter** types—for example:

```
List<AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>>
```

#### AMI for ECS instance

```
  ECSOptmizedAMI:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>
    Default: /aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id
```

The above is based on [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/retrieve-ecs-optimized_AMI.html).

Comment: okay.. so can you please tell me what would be the parameter for obtaining a list of ECS optimized AMI Ids?

Comment: I have tried this before, but the problem is, it doesnt provide a list of such AMI Ids from which i can choose the one required like i mentioned in the question. If such a method is not supported..i will definitely accept this answer

Comment: @AdityaNair Sadly such lists are not supported. You can't do much about this, except just hard-coding the actuall AMIs yourself.

Comment: okay thanks..i'm gonna go with this one then @Marcin

Comment: @AdityaNair No problem. Hopefully one day, such lists will be supported.